# Using getResourceAsStream on jar loaded by Class.forName(...)

Tags: java, class, jar

Now, before I start - I'm new to Java, and I have kind of thrown myself in at the deep end.

I have a system where I can load classes into my application from jar files in the form of plugins:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urlList);
// urlList is a 1 slice URL[] with a single URL to a jar file in it
Class<?> toolClass = Class.forName(className, true, loader);
// className is a String with the main class name in the jar
```

All that is fine and dandy - I can call methods within that loaded class, and it all works.

Now, I'd like to be able to have various resources stored within that jar file and have the class be able to access them.  I have been looking at getResourceAsStream(), which looks like it should be the way to go:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/to/my/test.txt");
```

... except it always returns null.  I have been staring at examples and other forum posts etc all about this function, but none of them seem to be with my specific circumstances:

1. The jar file is loaded at run-time using a URLClassLoader.
2. The jar file is not in the classPath.

So is what I am trying to do in these circumstances actually possible, or will I have to resort to manually unpacking the jar file to get at the resources? (I'd rather not do that to be honest.)

---

**Edit:** Here are the functions I am using:

Load a jar file:

```
public void loadPlugin(File jar)
{
    try {
        URL[] urlList = new URL[1];
        urlList[0]  = jar.toURI().toURL();

        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urlList);

        String className = null;
        className = findClassInZipFile(jar); // This just walks the zip file looking for the class

        if (className == null) {
            return;
        }

        JarFile jf = new JarFile(jar);
        Manifest manifest = jf.getManifest();
        Attributes manifestContents = manifest.getMainAttributes();

        Map pluginInfo = new LinkedHashMap();
        pluginInfo.put("version", manifestContents.getValue("Version"));
        pluginInfo.put("compiled", manifestContents.getValue("Compiled"));
        pluginInfo.put("jarfile", jar.getAbsolutePath());

        Class<?> toolClass;
        try {
            toolClass = Class.forName(className, true, loader);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Tool tool = (Tool) toolClass.newInstance();

        // If the setInfo method doesn't exist we don't care.
        try {
            tool.setInfo(pluginInfo);
        } catch (Exception blah) {
        }
        plugins.put(className, tool);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the function in the resultant class:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("uecide/app/tools/test.txt");
        if (in == null) {
            System.err.println("FAIL!!!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the jar file looks like:

```
   0 Fri Jun 28 16:52:32 BST 2013 META-INF/
 140 Fri Jun 28 16:52:30 BST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   0 Fri Jun 28 16:52:32 BST 2013 uecide/
   0 Fri Jun 28 16:52:32 BST 2013 uecide/app/
   0 Fri Jun 28 16:52:32 BST 2013 uecide/app/tools/
1880 Fri Jun 28 16:52:32 BST 2013 uecide/app/tools/ExportToMPLABX.class
2754 Fri Jun 28 16:52:32 BST 2013 uecide/app/tools/test.txt
```

Comment: It should be absolutely fine. I suspect you're providing the wrong resource name. For example, resource names are case-sensitive - have you double-checked the *exact* name you're providing?

Comment: Resource paths must start with a `/`! You don't have a `/` in your example, that is probably your problem here

Comment: @fge: this is incorrect. They must start with a `/` if using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to start at the root and not at the class's package. If using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, they must not start with a `/`.

Comment: What is `this` in your example code? Is it the same object as the one creating the URLClassLoader, or is it an instance of the class loaded from the jar?

Comment: @JBNizet ah, OK, I stand corrected then

Comment: @JBNizet `this` is an instance of the loaded class.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's one of the first things I checked - I copied and pasted the name from `jar -tvf myFile.jar` to be sure, and it's just the same.

Comment: @Majenko: Can you provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem? As I say, it really *should* be fine...

Comment: @JonSkeet I will try.  I didn't write the original code though, so I don't know if I can.  I'll give you the functions as they stand though.

Comment: @Majenko: Have you double-checked that `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` is returning the classloader you expect? It's possible that it's delegating to another one in Class.forName...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, you got it there :)  From the loader function: java.net.URLClassLoader@71ec7e25 - from the loaded function: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@29af45f4  So I guess the question now is how do I get the right launcher?

Comment: @JonSkeet One answer: pass the loader to the object after construction (tool.setLoader(loader);) - works, but isn't that nice really.  Well - I say "works" - it doesn't complain, but it doesn't get the right data from the file.  It just gets me a string of garbage.

Comment: @JonSkeet correction - it works fine, I just wrongly assumed that printing a byte array would cast it to a string for me, but it didn't.  So, is there a better way of getting the right loader?

Comment: How do classloaders share the `Tool` interface?

Answer (score 1):

As discovered, the problem is that the new classloader is first delegating to the parent classloader, which is finding the class.

Options:

- Make sure that the current classloader *doesn't* have the class you're trying to load
- Specify a parent classloader reference (possibly `null`?) when you construct the new `URLClassLoader`

Comment: Using null for the parent classLoader for the URLClassLoader causes it to go belly up with unable to find class.

Comment: @Majenko: That's interesting - that suggests there's something wrong with how it's finding the jar file. Hmm - worth debugging into, I suspect.

Comment: I guess I'll just stick to passing the loader to the class at load time.  I don't think I have the spare brain capacity to get my head around this.